# Spring Cloud Stream 4.0 Release Notes?

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, release-notes

We are currently using SCS v3.2 and I was wondering if there are any release notes for 4.0 in terms of breaking changes/deprecations? I know the annotation model is one item (which is fine for us - we started on the functional model).

I checked https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/ as well as searching in the (old) gitter which brought me here to stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this work for you: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/wiki/4.0-Migration-guide ?

Comment: ugh - yea that's perfect... looked everywhere but there thanks!